# Multiple Layouts in Ember.js?

Tags: layout, ember.js

Coming from a Rails background, you can have multiple Layouts - for say, anonymous user pages and then authenticated pages.

Is this possible with Ember?

I've tried declaring a new templateName in my UsersRouter, with no avail.

I've also checked this guide: http://emberjs.com/guides/views/adding-layouts-to-views/

But it doesn't seem to be working :/

Comment: can you show what you have tried and is not working?

Answer (score 6):

You can use `{{render}}` inside an `if` helper to show different layouts.

For instance if you have an `ApplicationController` that has `login` and `logout` action handlers, and a corresponding `loggedIn' property.

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  loggedIn: false,

  login: function() {
    this.set('loggedIn', true);
  },

  logout: function() {
    this.set('loggedIn', false);
  }
});
```

The you can bind to the `loggedIn` property inside the application template like so.

```
<script type='text/x-handlebars' data-template-name='application'>
<button {{action login }}>Login</button>
<button {{action logout }}>Logout</button>

{{#if loggedIn}}
  {{render 'user'}}
{{else}}
  {{render 'guest'}}
{{/if}}

</script>
```

Where `user` and `guest` are corresponding templates.

```
<script type='text/x-handlebars' data-template-name='user'>
<h1>User layout</h1>
<div class='box user'>
{{outlet}}
</div>
</script>

<script type='text/x-handlebars' data-template-name='guest'>
<h1>Guest layout</h1>
<div class='box guest'>
{{outlet}}
</div>
</script>
```

Here's a working [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/itolih/2/).

Edit: To not use the application route based on some static criteria or loaded via `model` hooks, you can override the `renderTemplate` method of the `ApplicationRoute`.

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  renderTemplate: function() {
    var loggedIn = false;
    if (loggedIn) {
      this.render('user');
    } else {
      this.render('guest');
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Ahh... okay. So - regardless, you have to do everything **within** the application template itself?

To clarify: there is no way to have, say, an application template and an admin template.

Instead, you have to have an application template, that holds certain logic to render specific child templates.

Is that correct?

Comment: Not necessarily. I used the application template as an example. You can do this within a route specific template too.

Comment: Ahh, ok - so a route specific template.

Comment: So, if I have a route:


    `App.Router.map, function() {`
      `this.resource("users")`
    `});`


I can set this route to *not* use the application template?

Comment: No the application template is the parent container template(Something like layout common to everything). You can change the template used to render `users` either like above or in the Route via the [`renderTemplate'](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/rendering-a-template/) hook method.

Comment: So then, to clarify: There is no way to *not* use the application template, as it is the parent container.

Every other layout/template is generated within the application template, and there is no way to have multiple application templates?

Sorry for the continued clarification - just trying to wrap my brain around all this! :)

Comment: Ok, I see now. You can do that too, via `renderTemplate` see my edited answer.

Comment: the edit section does not reload after a redirect `this.transitionTo()` so it does not refresh the template, any idea why?