# define multiple layouts emberjs

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ember.js

I am building an emberjs application I want to have two different layout for example application template and another template ,I don't want all my views to be rendered in the application template ,like in rails when you can specify to have multiple layouts for different controllers

Comment: http://emberjs.com/guides/views/adding-layouts-to-views/ or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17285660/multiple-layouts-in-ember-js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

these is the answer I got from emberjs discussion forum

Create two views for the two layouts with the "layoutName" property:

```
  App.MainLayoutView = Ember.View.extend({ layoutName: 'layout/main', });
```

and:

```
  App.SecondaryLayoutView = Ember.View.extend({
  layoutName: 'layout/secondary',
 });
```

Create two templates for the layout, called "layout/main" and "layout/secondary".

Make sure that your views extends those layout views. For example, imaging the following route config:

```
 App.Router.map(function() {
 this.resource('users', function() { this.route('new'); 
this.route('login'); });
```

});

If you want all the users route to be using MainLayout and login to be using the Secondary layout, create two views:

```
 App.ProjectsView = App.MainLayoutView.extend();
```

and

```
 App.LoginView = App.SecondaryLayoutView.extend();
```

There is no need to create a view for "projects/new" because it is a nested route of projects, hence inheriting the layout of Projects.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 4):

Its actually pretty easy, just specify which template to render:

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  renderTemplate: function() {
    if (expression) {
      this.render('application');
    } else {
      this.render('site');
    }
  }
});
```

Via http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/rendering-a-template/